# How to handle sql Joins scenarios

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, objectcontext

I'm using EF along with mvc, for that I've a generic repository, unitOfWork implementation based on ObjectContext, no problem with CRUD so far. I'm just wondering how can/should I handle scenarios where I need to do the join with entities.

Comment: In general selects with joins can be achieved using LINQ but could you add an example of a hypothetical query or action you would like to execute to add some context?

Comment: no specific context in mind just figuring out breaking my ObjectCotnext implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to handle the situation. Joins are not necessary in most situations and generally avoided in EF.

```
var orders = orderRepository.GetAll();

var projection = orders.Where(o => o.Customer.Name == "Foo")
        .Select(o => new { o, o.Customer });
```

Generic Repository is a leaky abstraction. Implement specific repository for each entity and create method that does the join and return the result.

Comment: leaky abstraction yea I do agree with you but at least we still have the option for the explicit repositories if we face such issue in the future.

Comment: @user1162274 Actually you tell what you need and EF will do the joins if needed :)

Comment: `@Eranga:` +1 for good answer. `@user1162274:` Joins can be done explicitly but due to aggregate routing as shown by Eranga, you don't realy need it in most cases.